# org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound:1108

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i try to solved this problem with all solutions that i encountered in stackoverflow but none worked for me

this is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

this is my servlet-context-xml:

```
<!-- Enable @Controller annotation support -->
        <mvc:annotation-driven />

        <!-- Esta etiqueta es para mapear carpetas dentro de src/main/webapp 
             de lo contrario el servidor no las reconoceria
         -->
        <!--   <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />  -->


        <!-- Map simple view name such as "test" into /WEB-INF/PAGE/test.jsp -->
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/page/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="viewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver">
            <property name="basename" value="views" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="multipartResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"></bean>


        <!-- Scan classpath for annotations (eg: @Service, @Repository etc) -->
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.ieea.dao" />
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.ieea.controller" />
        <!-- Contenido agregador -->

        <mvc:annotation-driven />




        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        </bean>
        <!-- Contenido agregador -->

        <!-- JDBC Data Source. It is assumed you have MySQL running on localhost 
            port 3306 with username root and blank password. Change below if it's not 
            the case -->

        <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
            destroy-method="close">

            <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/******" />
            <property name="username" value="*****" />
            <property name="password" value="*****" />
            <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />

        </bean>


        <!-- Hibernate Session Factory -->
        <bean id="mySessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
            <property name="packagesToScan">
                <array>
                    <value>com.ieea.domain</value>
                </array>
            </property>



            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                </props>
                <!-- <value> hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect </value> -->

            </property>
        </bean>

        <!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
        <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />

        </bean>

        <!-- Activates annotation based transaction management -->
        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    </beans>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class UsuarioController {

    @Autowired UsuarioDAOImpl usuarioDAO;

    @RequestMapping(value = "lista", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testReporte(Model model) {

        try {
            System.out.println("Entre");
            List<Usuario> lista = usuarioDAO.encontrarTodosUsuarios();
            model.addAttribute("lista", lista);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "index";
    }

}
```

I think that problem is in the web.xml or servlet-context.xml
i don't have idea what happening with my application, other applications in spring never cause this problem.

org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound:1108 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/usuariosTest/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

Comment: You don't seem to have a handler for `/usuariosTest/`.

Comment: "i try to solved this problem with all solutions that i encountered in stackoverflow". So you say. But as you don't tell us which solutions you tried, and why they did not work, we have no reason to believe you.

Answer (score 1):

You may have not provided the request mapping for "/" i.e for for startup url.

Put a "/" url mapping in your controller. You need to first deploy it on server and start the server then hit the application url in browser.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String testReporte(Model model) {

    try {
        System.out.println("Entre");
        List<Usuario> lista = usuarioDAO.encontrarTodosUsuarios();
        model.addAttribute("lista", lista);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "index";
}
```

Comment: now show index.jsp but never enter to UsuarioController, should be show the list of users

Comment: Is your list from usuarioDAO is loading into lista list. If it is loading then how are you fetching that list index.jsp? Actually this "/" mapping is for you home page jsp. From that jsp you can call different actions like your "/lista" request mapping.
But as your are saying index.jsp is displaying so just check whether your list is loading from DAO or not?

Comment: never show "Entre" on consola, if  UsuarioController it works should be show a message in console or show some error from usuarioDAO no?

Comment: If you try to run this application by right click and run on server then it will not display on Console. You have to deployed it on server and start the server then hit the url in browser. It will display the list.